# Apache Derby connection pooling

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, derby

In ADO.net, connection pooling is [enabled by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx). In java and JDBC, that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a connection pool for JDBC that comes with java? If not, is there a connection pool that comes with the Apache Derby library?

I'm interested in connection pools that come out of the box, not libraries such as C3P0, DBCP and BoneCP.

Comment: Nope. You'll have to bite the bullet and use a big boy pool (although I wouldn't recommend any of the ones you mentioned).

Comment: you might wanna check out jpa. It's not exactly what you asked for but in case you don't know it it might be interresting